# SLIM PHP API Post - Parsing JSON array of objects

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, slim

I have route in SLIM PHP Framework:
`app->post('/details', 'addDetail')`;

then I trying to loop in AddDetail function over this JSON:

```
[{"sessionid":"65656367","action":"tst1","argument":"test2"},{"sessionid":"23123154","action":"trololo","argument":"test6"}]
```

And add each object to mysql db. But when I using any loop then I get error in response:

```
[internal function]: addDetail()
C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\Slim\Route.php(392): call_user_func_array('addDetail', Array)
C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\Slim\Slim.php(1052): Slim_Route->dispatch()
C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\index.php(12): Slim->run()
```

**So... How to parse json array of objects and add them through PHP Slim Framework?**

Of course when I have just one object in JSON, then all works perfect.

Comment: explode + json_decode() ??

Comment: Nope. PHP Slim is probably parsing all code so now I have new 500 error: `C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\index.php(66): explode('[{"sessionid":"...')<br />
#2 [internal function]: addDetail()<br />
#3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\Slim\Route.php(392): call_user_func_array('addDetail', Array)<br />
#4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\Slim\Slim.php(1052): Slim_Route->dispatch()<br />
#5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\tc\api\index.php(12): Slim->run()`

Comment: show more of your code

Comment: I trying just echo my array of objects and I getting this error...: `function addDetail() {
 $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
 $body = json_decode($request->getBody());
  
  
  echo $body;

}`